# Структура памяти БД

Tags: база-данных, oracle

Подскажите, где можно найти информацию об организации структур памяти БД Oracle?

Может быть есть какие книги или ссылочки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Считаю, что вы найдёте эту информацию в этих источниках:

- Oracle Concepts
- «Oracle для профессионалов», Том Кайт

Comment: Oracle Concepts как раз то, что мне нужно, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Для первого знакомства и понинимания структур памяти БД достаточно ознакомится с главой оф. документации [Memory Architecture](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/memory-architecture.html#GUID-913335DF-050A-479A-A653-68A064DCCA41).

Наглядно структуры памяти представлены на этом графике:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Основных компонентов структуры памяти БД три, это:

- **SGA** (*System Global Area* - глобальная область системы) Совместно используемый сегмент памяти, к которому обращаются все процессы БД.
- **PGA** (*Process Global Area* - глобальная область процесса) Приватная область памяти процесса или потока, недоступная другим процессам/потокам.
- **UGA** (*User Global Area* - глобальная область пользователя) Область памяти сессии пользователя. Эта область памяти может находиться либо в SGA, либо в PGA. Если сервер работает в режиме распределённого сервера, она располагается в SGA, если в режиме выделенного сервера, то в PGA.

Более детальное ознакомление с компонентами структур пямяти по ссылке выше займёт в среднем от получаса до часа времени.

Answer (score 1):

Что значит структура памяти баз данных? Вы хотите узнать как хранятся данные (к слову, они хранятся не только в памяти, а в основном на диске)?

Книга Тома Кайта "Oracle для профессионалов" многое должна прояснить.

Также (а точнее в первую очередь) необходимо ознакомиться с алгоритмами и структурами данных вообще, и для внешней памяти в частности.